# Accessing n-gram frequencies from a large file

Tags: performance, nlp, large-files, n-gram, memory-efficient

I'm quite new to natural language processing and java programming. I have a very large text file containing ngrams and related frequencies (aaprox. 250 mb). I need to get the frequency value, given an ngram, in program runtime. The ngram frequencies are provided as following in the file (example only) :

```
the quick 445
quick brown 458
brown fox 11
fox jumped 123
```

I tried reading the file at startup by populating a hashset...but it took nearly 1500 ms for a 18mb file (tested using System.currentTimeMillis()). Now I'm thinking of sorting the n-gram counts and dividing 250mb file into small chunks and populate a list and get frequencies on-demand by indexing the file set in a separate index and referring to it.

But, i'm not sure if there is another easier or more efficient way to do this. Please let me know if there is a better way to do this. (it's better if it's not using any script or a library...). Thank you all.

Comment: If reading 18 MB takes 1.5s, reading the full 250 MB will take about 20s. Is this really the bottleneck of your program? In my experience what you do with the n-grams after you have read them in is the slow part. Some of the code I write runs for days, so 20s make no difference whatsoever.

Comment: I really needed to reduce the program start-up time and it to me more memory efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @mbatchkarov that load time is usually not the most important optimization target. But runtime is often strongly correlated with memory footprint (memory access is slow, so the more of your working set you can fit in cache, the better).

Your initial approach of mapping each bigram to an Integer count(presumably in a java.util.HashMap) is sensible, but very memory-intensive. Your count file includes millions of bigrams, and each must be represented as a separate String. Those Strings consume (at minimum) about 40 bytes of memory, and each count requires an Integer object - about 20 bytes in most JVM implementations. My coarse back-of-the-envelope guess puts that data structure over a gigabyte.

But you can do better, by observing that while a bigram only occurs in your file (and your data structure) once, most individual words are repeated many times - and you can get away without storing them repeatedly.

I would start with a map from words to integer indices - e.g., from your example, the=0, quick=1, brown=2, and so on. I don't know the size of your lexicon, but a typical mapping for frequent English words might have a few tens or hundreds of thousands of words. So the String storage will be must smaller.

To store the counts, you can combine these integer word indices into a compound key, and use that key for your map. One easy 'combination' method is simply to bit-shift the index of the first word, and OR in the second index.

In pseudocode:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> lexicon = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

// Iterate through the file, mapping each word to 
for (String file line) {
  ... Parse out word1 and word2
  if (!lexicon.containsKey(word1)) {
      lexicon.put(word1, lexicon.size());
  }
  if (!lexicon.containsKey(word2)) {
      lexicon.put(word2, lexicon.size());
  }
}
```

Now, iterate through the file again, adding the counts to a separate count map.

```
HashMap<Long, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();

for (String file line) {
    ... Parse out word1, word2, and count
    int i1 = lexicon.get(word1);
    int i2 = lexicon.get(word2);
    long key = (i1 << 32) | i2;
    countMap.put(key, count);
}
```

Accessing a bigram count is similar to mapping it - look up the indices of both words, create the key, and lookup in your count map. That should trim your storage space considerably. But I'd go one step further, and replace the generic HashMaps with type-specific maps from something like [FastUtil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) or [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/). Primitive data structures will eliminate a lot of the ~12-20 byte overhead for each Long and Integer in your data maps.

The pseudocode above assumes you use 32-bit ints for your word indices, and combine them into 64-bit longs. If your lexicon is small enough, you could use 16-bit shorts and 32-bit ints instead, and save some more space.

Edit: I should have been clear that if you want to implement a full n-gram language model (trigram, 4-gram, etc.), there are much more efficient representations, and n-gram models are handled well by several libraries (I'd recommend you look at [OpenGRM](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/GRM/NGramLibrary) and [Lingpipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/)). But the pseudocode above is an easy and relatively efficient way to do a simple bigram model.

Comment: I like the idea of mapping words with integers. I will try to implement this method. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [BerkeleyLM](http://code.google.com/p/berkeleylm/) that is a special library for handling ngrams.